# Как поменять пробелы на %20 в Bash скрипте?

Tags: bash

Пишу скрипт на bash, который принимает запрос через read, вставляет его в ссылку и эту ссылку открывает. Нужно сделать так, что если запрос содержит пробелы, то они автоматически менялись на %20, так как %20 - это код пробела. Как это сделать?

Comment: `sed 's/ /%20/g'` или типа того?

Comment: ничего не происходит - ни ошибки, ни "успеха"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read LINE
LINE=$(echo $LINE | sed "s/ /%20/g")
echo $LINE
```

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж метка стоит bash, то и решать проблему будем с помощью bash

```
read -p 'Введите что-то там с пробелами: ' line
echo ${line// /%20}
```